# How to get mysql query optimizer to use an index without superfluous WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql

I have a table - note the unique key index `ix_messagelogtime`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `messagelog` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EventType` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MarketType` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `CountryCode` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `MarketId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Message` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_messagelogtime` (`Timestamp`,`Id`,`EventType`,`MarketType`,`CountryCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=107717644 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

And I have a query that I am expecting to hit the `ix_messagelogtime` index:

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    messagelog
WHERE 
    EventType = 1 AND 
    MarketType = 'MyMarket'
ORDER BY 
    Timestamp, id
```

EXPLAIN for this query shows that a table scan will be used and running the query takes 20 seconds to complete.

[image: EXPLAIN1]

I have tried using a `USE INDEX` and `FORCE INDEX` hint and it still uses a full table scan. The only way I can get it to use the index is if I add superfluous WHERE clauses for Id and Timestamp (that match every row in the table and thus have no effect on the resultset). If I force the use of the index in this way, the query completes in a much faster time of 4 seconds.

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    messagelog
WHERE 
    EventType = 1 AND 
    MarketType = 'MyMarket' AND
    Id > 0 AND
    Timestamp > 0
ORDER BY 
    Timestamp, id
```

[image: EXPLAIN2]

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong? I would prefer a cleaner way to get the query optimizer to use the index.

Comment: You should not just put all columns into the index and hope the optimizer picks the right ones. Besides making it unique does not make sense. Make an index with just the columns you filter on.

Comment: I chose the index columns because they are the two columns I use in the ORDER BY, plus the 2 columns I use in the WHERE clause. As Tim pointed out in my accepted answer, the WHERE columns should be covered before the ORDER BY columns in the index. The mistake I made was getting this backwards - covering the ORDER BY columns before the WHERE columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current index on `(Timestamp, Id, EventType, MarketType, CountryCode)` is that the columns are out of order with regard to the order of the critical portions of the query.  Your composite index should first and foremost cover the `WHERE` clause, and then optionally the other parts.  I suggest this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON messagelog (EventType, MarketType);
```

This completely covers the `WHERE` clause.